# divide data in one column into more column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want to do this in Microsoft Excel 2007

This a one column. I have 20098 data in one column like below.

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   131
>   1
>   31
>   31
>   31
>   31
>   41

I want to rearrange those data like this how can i do it

> 1         4    7   1   31
>   2     5     8   31  31
>   3     6     131 31  41

Comment: Columns go from top to bottom, rows go from left to right. What do you have, and how would you like to have it organized?

Comment: no no its a column. it's problem when in pasting it

Comment: But do you want it split into three rows or three columns?

Comment: you will need vba to achieve this i think

Answer (score 3):

If your data was in column A then in cell B1 put
`=OFFSET($A1,3*(COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$1)),)`
and copy down and right to split your data as desired

[image]

Comment: `offset` is a volatile function, it will slow down calculations for 20 000+ rows i'm affraid...

Comment: @deathApril perhaps you should test that before downvoting on a optimisation constraint the OP didn't raise. The 20,000 cells (not rows as you posted) calculated instantly on my machine.

Comment: perhaps,, but there is no way for me to revoke the downvote if you don't edit your answer ;)

Comment: @deathApril I ran FastExcel V3, your 21000 cell calc (using `INDEX($A:$A,(COLUMN()-2)*3 + ROW())`) ran in 13.04ms, my 21000 cell calc in 13.81ms. Edit forthcoming ... :)

Comment: can you test regular excel optimised recalculation (where difference between volatile functions might be visible)? e.g. after entering formula in D5 `=D2` - but you are right, the performance is not an issue in this case

Comment: @LasithMalinga In that case why not close out the question by accepting an answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

use this formula in all 3 rows and 6700 columns of the resulting range:

```
=INDEX($A:$A;(COLUMN()-first_column)*3 + ROW()-first_row+1)
```

where `first_column` is `=column(..)` and `first_row` is `=row(..)` of the cell where you want to have the 1st value

e.g. if you use B1:IWS3 range to list the results, the formula will be:

```
=INDEX($A:$A;(COLUMN()-2)*3 + ROW())
```

Comment: @LasithMalinga please accept an answer you are most happy with ;)